# Multiple folders/files preview

Tags: nautilus, 19.10

When I open multiple folders, if i click on the nautilus icon, it'll open the last folder i opened; if a click on it for the second time, it'll show the preview of all the opened folders.

Is there a way to show the preview when i click on it for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the setting of Ubuntu dock with the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'previews'
```

To undo and reset to default, issue the command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

Comment: great solution, thank you very much.